# Wont apply formula to last row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, insert, row, vba

I am trying to add a last row, then put formulas in particular cells in that last row. When I run what I have, it adds the formula to the OLD last row, not the one I have newly created. Can you help please?

```
Sub AddDataRow()

    Dim tableName As String
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim lastRow As Range

    tableName = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set sheet = Range(tableName).Parent
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
        If Application.CountBlank(lastRow) < lastRow.Columns.Count Then
            table.ListRows.Add
        End If
    End If

     lastRow.Columns("L").Formula = "=A1+B1"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a row then your last row moved down one row.

you will need to determine your last row again before `lastRow.Columns("L").Formula = "=A1+B1"`.

Add another `Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range` before the line above.